# Can the URL of Sharepoint be changed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, redirect, domain

I'm just curious if there is a way of changing the URL from:
http://example.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet to http://intranet.example.com?

Thank you.

Comment: no not possible in SharePoint online

Comment: @GautamSheth is it possible outside of Sharepoint Online? as in, via PowerShell?

Comment: nope not possible via PowerShell. Are you asking for SP On Prem ? sorry if i misunderstood the question :(

Comment: @GautamSheth You didn't misunderstand the question at all, I was asking for SP Online, what is Prem?

Comment: OnPrem == you have your own hardware. On those servers, you have installed SharePoint product. In case of Online, Microsoft takes care of these details :). So, in SharePoint Online, you cant have vanity URLs

Comment: @GautamSheth that's a shame :/ thank you very much for the quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like stated in the comments. No, it's currently not supported to use custom domains on SharePoint Online.

The reasons for this are many, part technical and part business.

You can't even change the subdomain since that would require another subscription:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name

Cheers.

Comment: That's a shame, thank you for replying!